# What is the API to delete a photo using the Sony Camera Remote API?

Tags: camera, sony

Is it possible to delete images remotely using an API call for Sony cameras that support the Sony Camera Remote API?

Taking pictures is not possible once the camera memory card gets full and there seems to be no way provided to remotely delete images or erase the card. This is with the HDR-AS100, I assume other cameras have similar limitation.

If not possible here are two solutions that would resolve the issue for us:

- Provide an API to enumerate/read/delete images stored on the camera memory card, or at the very least allow for an API to delete the picture returned by actTakePicture
- Have an option in actTakePicture to specify not to store the image on the memory card, at least not permanently. i.e. erased once next picture is taken.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no API to do this unfortunately.  We appreciate the feedback though and I will pass this on to our API team as a suggestion.

Comment: Great. I hope these can come in a near future firmware update. Especially for the HDR-AS100 which we're looking at using for long term photography projects.

For this purpose having an 'always on' mode for the camera would be essential as well. That is as soon as AC power is on the camera is on and wi-fi connectivity is available.

Comment: It's been a year. And I see the delete functionality is being added however only to new models. Will old models get this basic delete functionality or are the cameras I purchased useless and need to be replaced?